# Call a set of functions in order in an array

Tags: powershell

I want to create some arrays of function names, and then call those depending on what parameters are passed to my script. Is this possible? In the crude example below, if I pass in `2` as a parameter to the script, I want the `$twoFuncs` list of functions to be called **in order**.

```
param ($whichFuncs)
Function a{ Write-Host "Executing function a" }
Function b{ Write-Host "Executing function b" }
Function c {Write-Host "Executing function c" }
$twoFuncs = @("a","b")
$threeFuncs = @("c","b","a")

if($whichFuncs -eq 2)
{
    # execute functions a + b
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is the call operator `&` and a foreach-loop.

```
PS C:\Users\Frode> $twoFuncs | ForEach-Object { & $_ }
Executing function a
Executing function b
```

Comment: I always suggest avoiding Invoke-Expression.  The call operator works perfectly here, Invoke-Expression will get messy if the function take arguments.

Comment: I know, that's why I quickly added the call operator after I posted my answer. :) Made it more clear by removing `iex` now, though I usuall like to show multiple approaches.

Comment: @FrodeF. +1 for multiple approaches :)

Answer (score 1):

How about using a switch?

```
param ($whichFuncs)
Function a{ Write-Host "Executing function a" }
Function b{ Write-Host "Executing function b" }
Function c {Write-Host "Executing function c" }
switch ($whichFuncs)
 {
   2 {a;b}
   3 {c;b;a}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple. I'm trying a basic workflow engine, and I just noticed powershell 3+ workflows. I'll do some research on workflows and see if it gives me anything extra.